# Send email using "on behalf of" using apache common Email

Tags: java, email, apache-commons, email-client

I want to send email from my application by adding "on behalf of" address. Currently I am using apache common Email to send email and it seems I couldn't specify sender in there. As I can see email headers I need to set different values for sender and from to show email receive as "on behalf of" in the mail client.

Can anyone please help me to do this using java email client or can I achieve this using same apache common client? Solution needs to be work with most of common email clients like outlook, gmail etc..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can set only one email address as From. In my scenario I need to set from as two addresses. Like "Test <test@test.com> on behalf of John <john@test.com>". In From we can't set more than one email. So I need to set it in sender and from

Comment: Thanks @ScaryWombat it worked.

Answer (score 2):

As per [link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21687280/Setting-On-Behalf-of-in-the-Mail.html)

you can do

```
 msg.addHeader("Sender", "My Friend <xxxxxx@xxxxx.com>");
```

Comment: Setting up different "From" and "Sender" header cause to add "On Behalf of" correctly in outlook email client. But I have noticed this way is not showing properly in Gmail or yahoo client( it still showing just from address). Does anyone know what is the reason.